# Shared lock with two exclusive lock groups

Tags: c++, locking, mutex, semaphore

I have two methods "log" and "measure" that should never execute at the same time.
So I tried to use a "std::mutex" to do this as follows:

```
void log(std::string message)
{
    mtx.lock();
    someLogFunctionality();
    mtx.unlock();
}

void measure()
{        
    mtx.lock();
    someMeasureFunctionality();
    mtx.unlock();
}
```

Now it turned out that it also shall be possible to call "log" multiple times in parallel without locking and the same applies for "measure", too. (Reason: someLogFunctionality() and someMeasureFunctionality() interfere with each other but the same method may be called multiple times parallely)

I had a look at "std::shared_mutex" then, but there are two problems for me:

1.) With shared_mutex I could use lock_shared for only one of the methods (log or measure) but then the other one would have to use the exclusive lock (and could again not be executed multiple times in parallel)

```
void log(std::string message)
{
    mtx.lock_shared();
    someLogFunctionality();
    mtx.unlock_shared();
}

void measure()
{        
    mtx.lock(); // This should also be shared but among another "group"
    someMeasureFunctionality();
    mtx.unlock();
}
```

2.) I can't use C++17 (constraint in the environment that I'm working with)

Do you have any suggestions for me how I could realize this?

Comment: This is an instance of the "single-lane bridge problem". What you want can be done using semaphores. I don't remember exactly how to do it so I'm not going to write an answer, but if you search for that phrase you should find some guides.

Comment: Maybe a recursive mutex? https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/recursive_mutex

Comment: BTW, you should remove the C language tag.  The C language does not have `std::string` nor `std::shared_mutex`.  The C language doesn't have namespaces.  Please update your language tags as appropriate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the reply from alexb I have written the following mutex class which currently works for me (only tried out in a simple multithreaded example application so far)

Please note that it is not protected against "starvation". In simple words: It is not ensured that that lockMeasure will ever get the lock if lockLogging is called high-frequently (and the other way round).

```
class MyMutex
{
private:
    std::atomic<int> log_executors;
    std::atomic<int> measure_executors;

    std::mutex mtx;
    std::condition_variable condition;

public:
    MyMutex() : log_executors(0), measure_executors(0) {}
    
    ~MyMutex() {}

    void lockMeasure()
    {   
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mtx);

        while(log_executors) {
            condition.wait(lock); 
        }
        measure_executors++; 
    }
    
    void unlockMeasure()
    {   
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mtx);

        measure_executors--; 
        if (!measure_executors)
        {
          condition.notify_all();
        }
    }
    
    void lockLogging()
    {         
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mtx);

        while(measure_executors) {
          condition.wait(lock); 
        }
        log_executors++;
    }

    void unlockLogging()
    {         
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mtx);

        log_executors--; 
        if (!log_executors)
        {
          condition.notify_all(); 
        }
    }

    static MyMutex& getInstance()
    {
        static MyMutex _instance;
        return _instance;
    }    
};
```

Usage:

```
void measure()
{
    MyMutex::getInstance().lockMeasure();

    someMeasureFunctionality();

    MyMutex::getInstance().unlockMeasure();
}

void log()
{
    MyMutex::getInstance().lockLogging();

    someLogFunctionality();

    MyMutex::getInstance().unlockLogging();
}
```

Comment: I went with the route of making a `parallel_locks` object that generates individual `parallel_lock` objects that are actual locks, so are usable with `std::unique_lock` as per normal RAII patterns. http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8bfb052e0be10b93

Comment: Also note: your unlock methods don't actually need to grab the mutex, if you're crafty.  Also `condition.wait` can take a predicate, to avoid putting it in a loop.

Comment: Why is the mutex static?

Comment: It's static because it is used as a singleton in a header only library. And measure/log are methods of a class that might be instantiated multiple times in the application.

Answer (score 1):

You need some barrier logic which is more complicated than shared_mutex (BTW, shared_mutex is not best choice for multiplatform compilation). For example, you can use mutex, conditional variable, and 2 variables for barrier sync. It does not take CPU and you may not use sleeps for check.

```
#include <mutex>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <atomic>

std::atomic<int> log_executors = 0;
std::atomic<int> measure_executors = 0;

std::mutex mutex;
std::condition_variable condition;

void log(std::string message) {
  {
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mutex);

    log_executors++;  // Register current executor and prevent from entering new measure executors

    // Wait until all measure executors will go away
    while(measure_executors) {
      condition.wait(lock);  // wait condition variable signal. Mutex will be unlocked during wait
    }
  }

  // here lock is freed
  someLogFunctionality(); // execute logic


  {
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mutex);
    log_executors--;  // unregister current execution
    condition.notify_all();  // send signal and unlock all waiters
  }
}

void measure()
{        
  {
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mutex);

    measure_executors++;  // Register current executor and prevent from entering new log executors
    while(log_executors) {
      condition.wait(lock);  // wait until all measure executors will gone
    }
  }

  someMeasureFunctionality();

  {
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mutex);
    measure_executors--;  // unregister current execution
    condition.notify_all(); // send signal and unlock all waiters
  }
}
```

Comment: `stD::condition_variable` just takes a  function pointer, just `while(measure_executors) {
      condition.wait(lock);` -> `condition.wait(lock, [](){ return measure_executors; })`

Comment: You modify `log_executors` and `measure_executors` without holding the mutex. While they are atomic, that doesn't prevent race conditions between code that holds the mutex and code that accesses the atomics. (Think about it. What does the mutex protect?)

Comment: Consider: Thread A is calling `log` it holds the mutex. It discovers that `measure_executors` is 1. Then thread B, calling `measure` and not holding the lock decrements `measure_executors` and then calls `notify_all`. Then thread A runs again, calling `wait` to wait for something *that has already happened*. This code is a disaster. The mutex doesn't protect anything, making the `wait` function vulnerable to deadlock.

Comment: sure, fixed with lock protection on decrement. Also condition.wait_for(lock, std::chrono::milliseconds(milliseconds)) instead condition.wait(lock) can be used to fully prevent race conditions

Comment: Unfortunately I am getting deadlocks - both methods stop at "condition.wait(lock);".

Assumption: "measure" stops at condition.wait() because log_executors == 1 (this unlocks the mutex) -> while waiting, "log" is called again (log_executors = 2) and also stops at condition.wait() -> first "log" finishes (log_executors = 1) -> This wakes up "measure" but it still waits because log_executors is not yet 0 => Deadlock because log_executors can never become 0 ("log" is also waiting at condition.wait() for measure to complete)

Solution: When I move increment after while loop it currently works

Comment: Both paths increment their counter and then wait for the other counter to hit zero, so this code deadlocks, yes.

Comment: Yours has a deadlock, but I attempted to implement this idea wrapped behind mutex classes, to make it easy to use.  While I was at it, I also extended it to N objects, rather than just 2. http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/774af8ba8a5adce3

Answer (score -1):

You can have a master lock granting access to a semaphore variable:

```
void log(std::string message)
{
    acquire(LOG);
    someLogFunctionality();
    release(LOG);
}

void measure()
{        
    acquire(MEASURE);
    someMeasureFunctionality();
    release(MEASURE);
}

void acquire(int what) {
    for (;;) {
        mtx.lock();
        if (owner == NONE) {
            owner = what;
        }
        if (owner == what) {
            // A LOG was asked while LOG is running
            users[owner]++;
            mtx.unlock();
            return;
        }
        mtx.unlock();
        // Some sleep would be good
        usleep(5000);
    }
}

void release(int what) {
    mtx.lock();
    if (owner != what) {
        // This is an error. How could this happen?
    }
    if (users[what] <= 0) {
        // This is an error. How could this happen?
    }
    users[what]--;
    if (0 == users[what]) {
        owner = NONE;
    }
    mtx.unlock();
}
```

In this case, for example:

```
owner is NONE
LOG1 acquires LOG. It can do so because owner is NONE
MEASURE1 acquires LOG. It starts spinning in place because owner != MEASURE
MEASURE2 acquires LOG. It starts spinning in place because owner != MEASURE
LOG2 acquires LOG. It can do so because owner is LOG, users[LOG]=2
LOG2 releases LOG. users[LOG]=1
LOG1 releases LOG. users[LOG]=0, so owner becomes NONE
MEASURE2 by pure chance acquires mtx before MEASURE1, finds owner=NONE and goes
MEASURE1 finds owner=MEASURE and sets users[MEASURE]=2
```

In the above, note that the second call to measure() actually executed a bit earlier. This should be OK. But if you want to keep the calls "serialized" even if they happen in parallel, you'll need a stack for each owner and more complex code.

Comment: The sleep/spin approach is really ugly.